# How to tell if a given file can be added via Photos framework to Photo Library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, video

I'm wondering if anyone knows how to tell if a given file can be added via the iOS Photos framework, ie. if it is a video and if it is in the correct format. Specifically:

Given a big NSData* pointing to what might be a video, how can one tell if

```
[PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL:fileURL]
```

would work, without trying it every time? is there some efficient way to tell?
The only other metadata I have are the filename, and the file-size.

I don't have any experience working with video on iOS. I'm hoping there's some way to attempt to create some video object with the NSData and see if it works, before trying to add it via the Photos framework.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AVAsset` for this. Create an asset using `assetWithURL` method and use the usability properties of `AVAsset`. All are boolean properties to check usability of asset.

You can check 5 properties:

- `hasProtectedContent`
- `playable`
- `exportable`
- `readable`
- `composable`

There are many other properties also, to check other parameters of video if you want. Refer to [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAsset_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAsset) for further information.

Comment: Gonna try this out and accept if it works! :D thanks